# Regressive function on singular cardinal with bounded preimage for each point

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

The claim below is considered obvious in Levy's Basic Set Theory:

> If $\kappa$ is a singular cardinal, then there is a regressive function $f:\kappa\to \text{cf}(\kappa)$, such that for all $\gamma<\text{cf}(\kappa)$, the preimage $f^{-1}"\{\gamma\}$ is bounded below $\kappa$.

I don't see why this claim holds. The intuitive thing to try first is to take a cofinal sequence $(\alpha_i\mid i<\text{cf}(\kappa))$ in $\kappa$ with ordertype $\text{cf}(\kappa)$, and think of this sequence as breaking $\kappa$ into intervals. So we would map each $x$ in the interval $(\alpha_i, \alpha_{i+1}]$ to $\alpha_i$. But this doesn't work, because it is unclear where $\alpha_\lambda$ themselves will be mapped to, for any limit ordinal $\lambda$. Enumerating the limit points in $(\alpha_i\mid i<\text{cf}(\kappa))$ and trying a similar map doesn't seem to help either, because we'll need to worry about limits of limits, and so on.

(Edit: as you can see, I was completely confusing myself above. I was trying to map things to the elements on the cofinal sequence, instead of their indices. As a result the map I was trying to define has range way above $\text{cf}(\kappa)$!)

So I am a little bit lost now. Do we need to use Fodor's lemma somehow?

Comment: Fun fact, Azriel wrote the whole book in Plain $\rm\TeX$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The regressive condition is trivial to satisfy since $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)<\kappa$: just let $f(\alpha)=0$ for all $\alpha\leq\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)$.  Then, you can pick a sequence $(\alpha_i)_{i<\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)}$ with limit $\kappa$ and define $f(\alpha)$ to be the least $i$ such that $\alpha<\alpha_i$ if $\alpha>\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)$.

Comment: Wow, I was so occupied with mapping things to elements on that cofinal sequence, without thinking of mapping things to the indices on that cofinal sequence (and my map in the question has range way beyond $\text{cf}(\kappa)$). Thanks very much!